# ¿Cómo actualizar campos dinamicos en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo un formulario como el siguiente:

[image: formulario]

Dentro de este formulario hay una tabla dinámica donde a través de jquery puedo agregar o eliminar campos de entrada dinámicos. 
**Esta tabla registra información sobre las herramientas que se utilizan para la fabricación de una pieza**
El modelo principal es pieza y a su vez, **dentro de la tabla participan estas dos entidades: tool (color rojo) e insert (color azul).**

**Tengo problemas al querer actualizar las herramientas que pertenecen a una pieza que ya ha sido creada.**
Realice 2 tipos de pruebas para mostrar el problema.
**En la primera prueba, estoy creando una pieza y asociando 2 nuevas herramientas , como puede ver en la imagen, se creó con éxito.**

[image: crear_pieza]

**En la segunda prueba, estoy actualizando la pieza creada , luego estoy modificando algunos campos de propios de pieza y al mismo tiempo estoy modificando las herramientas asociadas.**

¿Que pasó?

La pieza se actualizó, es decir, los campos propios de pieza se actualizaron correctamente. 
**En el caso de las herramientas en lugar de actualizar las que ya se han creadas, sucedió lo contrario, se creó una nueva herramienta como se puede ver en la imagen.**

[image: actualizar_pieza]

Esta es mi tabla con campos dinamicos de entrada:

```
       <div class="box-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">              
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">Posición</th>
                        <th width="20%">Herramienta</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Inserto</th>                 
                        <th width="20%">Calidad</th>                       
                        <th width="5%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></th>
                    </tr>
                    @forelse ($piece->tools as $p)  
                        <tr> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][position]" value="{{ $p->position }} " placeholder="Posición"  class="form-control select2" /></td>                                                 
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_tool]" value="{{ $p->code_tool }}"  placeholder="Herramienta"class="form-control" /></td>                        
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][code_insert]" value="{{ $p->insert->code_insert }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>                       
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][quality]" value="{{ $p->insert->quality }}" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control" /></td>                      
                        </tr> 
                    @empty
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td>
                    @endforelse                                     
                </table> 
            </div>
```

Mi update method se ve asi:

```
                $piece  = Piece::with('tools')->findOrFail($id); 


                $addmore = $request->addmore;
                $arrTool = [];


                foreach($addmore as $add)
                {
                    $insert = Insert::where('id', $add)->updateOrCreate([
                        'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                        'quality'     => $add['quality']
                    ]);  

                    $tools = $insert->tools()->updateOrCreate([
                        'position'   => $add['position'],
                        'code_tool'  => $add['code_tool'],                   
                        'insert_id'  => $insert->id                            
                    ]);                     

                    $arrTool[] = $tools->id;                  
                }
```

Por favor alguien que guie en la solucion, **que tendria que modificar en mi método para que solo se actualicen las herramientas que ya se crearon**, en mi caso se está creando una nueva herramienta.

Comment: Necesitan ver mi modelos relacionados? por favor me avisan!

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, gracias por tus aclaraciones, estoy siguiendo tus indicaciones, no me queda claro si solo modifico el input: ```name="addmore[{{$p->id}}][position]"```o tambien lo replico a los demas input?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ genial ya he  modificado lo que me has indicado, vuelvo a actualizar la  pieza que ya ha sido creada pero me agregan nuevas herramientas, creo que esto no esta bien: ```$insert = Insert::where('id', $add)->updateOrCreate```, y esto tambien:  ```$tools = $insert->tools()->updateOrCreate```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si cambio esto: ```$insert = Insert::where('id', $add)->updateOrCreate``` a esto: ```$insert = Insert::where('id', $add)->update``` recibo un error como el siguiente: ```"message": "Call to a member function tools() on integer"```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sugiero ir al chat, ahora estoy agregado eso cambios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104822/discussion-between-rodrigo-ruiz-and-porloscerros-).

Answer (score 1):

**Gracias a la ayuda @porloscerrosΨ** he podido resolver esta problema que me tuvo atascado por unos dias.
Lo hicimos de esta manera:

1 arreglamos el indice en los nombres de los inputs name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]"

```
  <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]" value="{{ $p->position }} " placeholder="Posición" class="form-control select2"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][code_tool]" value="{{ $p->code_tool }}" placeholder="Herramienta"class="form-control"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][code_insert]" value="{{ $p->insert->code_insert }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][quality]" value="{{ $p->insert->quality }}" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td>
```

eso porque antes lo tenía hardcodeado a cero name="addmore[0][position]" y se iban a pisar cuando lo fuera a guardar en php.

2 arreglamos los métodos updateOrCreate para que usen como identificador las ids de los modelos en vez de todos los campos, eso para que no se cree uno nuevo cada vez que modificaba un campo.

```
                $addmore = $request->addmore;
                $arrTool = [];

                foreach($addmore as $add)
                {                                 
                    $insert = Insert::updateOrCreate(
                        [ 'id' => array_key_exists('insert_id', $add)? $add['insert_id']: null ],
                            [
                                'code_insert' => $add['code_insert'],
                                'quality' => $add['quality']
                            ]
                        );

                    $tools = $insert->tools()->updateOrCreate(
                        [ 'id' => array_key_exists('tool_id', $add)? $add['tool_id']: null ],
                            [
                            'position' => $add['position'],
                            'code_tool' => $add['code_tool'],
                            'insert_id' => $insert->id
                            ]
                        );

                    $arrTool[] = $tools->id;     
                }
```

3 para el punto 2 tuvimos que agregar un input con la id de cada modelo

```
<input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][insert_id]" value="{{ $p->insert->id }}" hidden/>
<input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][tool_id]" value="{{ $p->id }}" hidden/>
```

4 Para el punto 1, tuvimos que arreglar también el índice donde empezar, que estaba en cero, para que no pise los anteriores cuando ya había registros en BD

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla = $('#dynamicTable >tbody >tr').length;
    var i = cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla ? cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla: 0;  

    $("#add").click(function(){

        ++i;

        $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][position]" placeholder="Posición" class="form-control"/></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_tool]" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_insert]" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>  <td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][quality]" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td></tr>');

    });  

    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }); 

</script>
```

5 En el updateOrCreate tuvimos que atajar el caso de cuando era una fila nueva que no tuviese id

```
[ 'id' => array_key_exists('tool_id', $add)? $add['tool_id']: null ]
```